# Loading data (fixtures) the first time a Sails.js app is lifted

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I'm using Sails.js 0.10 RC7. When a developer checks out a project and runs it, I'd like to pre-populate some data into the database. This should be done only the first time the app is run (or maybe we should have this happen whenever new data is added to the fixture).

I could put the data in `config/bootstrap.js` but as I understand it, that is run each time `sails lift` is run. I'm OK doing this and writing some logic, but if there is already a convention for taking care of this, it'd be great to use it.

Just to be clear, I'm not specifically referring to test fixtures, but some data that is assumed to be available in any running environment.

Anyone already solve this problem?

Comment: For such things, you should use database migrations. There are many libraries for all database types, so find some appropriate one.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that is what I'm looking for. I'm curious to know what tools people are using to do this with Sails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We face this issue with nearly every Sails project we do at [Balderdash](http://balderdash.co/#!home).  We almost always solve it by building up data in the [bootstrap](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/config/bootstrap-js) and wrapping it in logic to detect whether the data already exists, just as you described.  Something like:

```
User.find({admin: true}).exec(function(err, adminUser) {
    // If an admin user exists, skip the bootstrap data
    if (adminUser) { return cb(); }
    // Otherwise, create data below...
});
```

It's not as robust as true "up/down" database migrations, but since we use the very convenient  (and schemaless) [disk adapter](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-disk) for development, it's simple to just wipe the database by erasing the data file, and lift Sails again to get a freshly bootstrapped copy.  We rarely miss the complications the db migrations entail, but we do realize that there are situations where they become necessary.  The Sails community has responded by coming up with some solutions (here's [one example](https://github.com/BlueHotDog/sails-migrations)), which is what we like to see!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm OK with doing something like this, and over the weekend I did create a shell script for devs to run. I just wanted to avoid the work if there was already a great solution in place.

Comment: It would be helpful to know where you usually put the bootstrap logic in the Sails project structure. Under `api/services`, separate file at the root or something else? I would like to know the convention you have found out to be the best.

Comment: @AkseliPalén Sails already comes with a bootstrap file in [`config/bootstrap.js`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/config/bootstrap-js).